# How do I display Custom Error Message in MediaElement

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

When MediaElement is unable to play a media file then it displays the error `"Could not open mediaFile someFile.avi"`. Can we customize this Error message or display a link instead of message so when user clicks  on it will be redirected to player site.

**Edit:**
I am creating custom MediaPlayer and updating the requirement onApplyTemplate as below:

```
 public class CustomMediaPlayer : MediaPlayer
    {
     public override void OnApplyTemplate()
            {
                  base.OnApplyTemplate();
                  //..
                  //..Other Controls and Events
                  MediaElement mediaElement = GetTemplateChild("mediaElement") as MediaElement;  
                  mediaElement.MediaFailed += (obj, Args) =>
                      {
                       //Code Goes Here

                      };

           }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach to the `MediaFailed` event hide the MediaElement and display whatever UI content you like.